# ehcache warning message " No configuration found"

Tags: hibernate, spring, ehcache

I have got following warning when the application start up.

```
2009-05-13 09:19:41,171 WARN  net.sf.ehcache.config.Configurator - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml found in the classpath:jar:file:/app/java/lib/ehcache-1.1.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
```

I found encache code in following url .. [ConfigurationFactory Code](http://ehcache.org/xref/net/sf/ehcache/config/ConfigurationFactory.html)

Application is trying to load ehcache.xml but could not find the file so then it loads  ehcache-failsafe.xml.I would like to know does this cause any problem to application ? what is impact loading ehcache-failsafe.xml ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Loading `ehcache-failsafe.xml` doesn't cause a **problem** per se; however it most likely isn't optimal for your application.

There's no way for EhCache developers to know what you intend to cache; thus `ehcache-failsafe.xml` included in distribution attempts to provide some "lowest common denominator" settings that would work more or less OK in most cases. You get a warning as a reminder to specify configuration that would be more appropriate for your specific needs.

Answer (score 34):

`ehcache.xml` should be introduced in your `classpath` and specifically in `WEB-INF/classes/`. Then, you can specify your needs in it according to your environment.

This is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="50000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"/>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="50000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="120"
           timeToLiveSeconds="120"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="false"
               diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />

    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="50000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />

</ehcache>
```

After 3 years, hope that my response can help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you re using Ehcache as a second level cache provider for hibernate change : hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path with net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName 
Ehcache will be able to find your configuration then.

Comment: This does not answer the original question though. The OP asked about the impact of the failsafe xml